# Typeorm + Express on Cloud Function for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, typeorm

I searched a lot but nothing about how to set a firebase cloud function using Typeorm and express.

I'm trying to build an api server with Express + Apollo server + TypeORM, but to connect to the DB with TypeORM, I need to do something like

```
createConnection().then(async connection => {
  // init server here
  app = express()
  ...
})
```

But to deploy to firebase, I have to do

```
export const server = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

How can I combine these?

Maybe I could do

```
export const server = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  createConnection().then(async connection => {
    // init server here
    app = express()
    ...
  })
})
```

But since it's Cloud Function, so every time a request come, a new instance is created, which mean a new connection is created. Is this OK? Wouldn't there be any speed issues?

---

UPDATE

```
import { connect } from './config';

const app = express()
export const server = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const connection = await connect();
  return app(req, res)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `./config` file where you establish a DB connection. Then, you can import it in your `index.ts` and use it as follows:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { connect } from './config';

export const server = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
     
    // Establish connection to DB
    const connection = await connect();

    const usersRepository = connection.getRepository(Users);

    // Count the users
    const count = await usersRepository.count();

    // Get all the users 
    const allUsers = await usersRepository.find();

    // SQL Query to fetch the users who are older than 21
    const query = await usersRepository.query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE AGE > 21');    

    response.send(allUsers);

});
```

If you still have doubts as to how to configure the config file, I believe that using this [sample code](https://github.com/fireship-io/201-cloud-functions-sql-typeorm/blob/master/functions/src/config.ts) along with the [typeORM configuration files](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-ormconfig.md) may be helpful.

I also recommend that you have a look at the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#use_a_web_framework) for examples about using Express.js in Cloud Functions for Firebase.

---

*Update*: To add Express + TypeORM to your Cloud Function for Firebase, you can do the following:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import {Request, Response} from "express";
import { connect } from './config';
import * as express from 'express';

// Initializing Express server and defined PORT
const PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

// Register '/' endpoint 
app.get('/', (request, response, next) => {
  response.send('Hello World from Cloud Firestore for Firebase');
});

// Register 'users' endpoint
app.get('/users', async function(request: Request, response: Response) {

  // Establish connection to DB
  const connection = await connect();

  const usersRepository = connection.getRepository(Users);

  // Get all the users 
  const allUsers = await usersRepository.find();

  response.json(allUsers);

});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on PORT', PORT);
});

// Exports the Express app as a single HTTP function
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Please see the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and TypeORM repository for [adding Express to the application](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/example-with-express.md).

Comment: Thx! Great example codes. Please see the updated question. Is that a valid way to combine express?

Comment: Sure, I just edited my answer. You will need to implement some code refactoring. You can use the code above and tweak it as needed. _Disclaimer_: The code is untested.